# compare 2variable in dict with xor gate and save in list

Tags: python

Hi I very basic python I have question to ask
this is my code

```
previous_data=[
    {'id':1,'data':[]},
    {'id':2,'data':[['A','11:00:00']]},
    {'id':3,'data':[['A','11:00:00'],['B','11:00:00']]},
    {'id':4,'data':[['A','11:00:00']]},
    {'id':5,'data':[['A','11:00:00'],['B','11:00:00']]},
    {'id':6,'data':[]}
]
current_data=[
    {'id':1,'data':[['A','12:00:00']]},
    {'id':2,'data':[]},
    {'id':3,'data':[['A','12:00:00'],['B','12:00:00']]},
    {'id':4,'data':[['A','12:00:00'],['B','12:00:00']]},
    {'id':5,'data':[['A','12:00:00']]},
    {'id':6,'data':[]}
]
count=0
data_add=[]
data_remove=[]
data_same=[]
for sub_prev,sub_current in zip(previous_data,current_data):
    for prev,curr in zip(sub_prev['data'],sub_current['data']):
        if not prev and curr:
            print(f"Add ID:{sub_current['id']}")
            for data in curr:
                print(f"data:{data}")
                data_add.append([sub_current['id'],data])
        elif  prev and not curr:
            print(f"Remove ID:{sub_current['id']}")
            for data in curr:
                print(f"data:{data}")
        elif  prev and  curr:
            print(f"same ID:{sub_current['id']}")
            for data in prev:
                print(f"data:{data}")
print(data_add)
```

I want to save dict seperates add remove and same by I think I use principle XOR-Gate
[enter image description here][1]
by I assume a= previous_data and b = current_data

```
     a b output
if   0 1 add data b
elif 1 0 remove data b
elif 1 1 same data b
```

but I my output from my code are

```
same ID:3
data:A
data:11:00:00
same ID:3
data:B
data:11:00:00
same ID:4
data:A
data:11:00:00
same ID:5
data:A
data:11:00:00
[]
```

but my concept are

```
add = [
    {'id':1,'data':[['A','12:00:00']]},
    {'id':4,'data':[['B','12:00:00']]}
]
remove = [
    {'id':2,'data':[['A','11:00:00']]},
    {'id':5,'data':[['B','11:00:00']]}
]
same= [
    {'id':3,'data':[['A','11:00:00'],['B','11:00:00']]}, 
    {'id':4,'data':[['A','11:00:00']]},
    {'id':5,'data':[['A','11:00:00']]}
]
so 
final=[
    {'id':1,'data':[['A','12:00:00']]},
    {'id':3,'data':[['A','11:00:00'],['B','11:00:00']]},
    {'id':4,'data':[['A','11:00:00'],['B','12:00:00']]},
    {'id':5,'data':[['A','11:00:00']]}
]
```

At last I know my question very similar and It's a stupid question but I am try all 3 week I don't know how to do this ?
I hope someone can help me,
thank you very much.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMMIe.png

Comment: Thank you for trying to ask your question in English. Unfortunately, it doesn't make sense. Maybe someone could help you to rephrase it

Comment: I think with the reproducible example and code there is enough to go on here. We can see the issue is nothing goes into the 'add' or 'remove' lists, and id 4 & 5 go into the 'same' list when they are different

Comment: In your current example data there should be no `{'id':3,'data':[['A','11:00:00'],['B','11:00:00']]}` in the expected `same` output, because `current_data` has `{'id':3,'data':[['A','12:00:00'],['B','12:00:00']]}`

Answer (score 1):

Loop through paired previous_data and current_data.
Check each piece of data to determine if it was added, removed, or remains the same.try this code

```
previous_data = [ ... ]  # use provided data
current_data = [ ... ]  # use provided data

add, remove, same, final = [], [], [], []

for p, c in zip(previous_data, current_data):
    added_data = [item for item in c['data'] if item not in p['data']]
    removed_data = [item for item in p['data'] if item not in c['data']]
    same_data = [item for item in p['data'] if item in c['data']]
    
    if added_data:
        add.append({'id': c['id'], 'data': added_data})
    if removed_data:
        remove.append({'id': p['id'], 'data': removed_data})
    if same_data:
        same.append({'id': p['id'], 'data': same_data})

    combined_data = same_data + added_data
    if combined_data:
        final.append({'id': p['id'], 'data': combined_data})

print("Added:", add)
print("Removed:", remove)
print("Same:", same)
print("Final:", final)
```